# how to see type of all the columns of a Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

My data is in a `csv` file.

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States   Romania 15
United States   Croatia 1
United States   Ireland 344
Egypt   United States   15
```

I read the file

```
scala> val data = spark.read.csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1                                                                               data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 1 more field]
```

the above shows me type of `_c0` and `_c1` only. How can I see all the columns and their types instead of the message `1 more field`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the first line got interpreted as data..

```
val data = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(<your path>)
data.printSchema
```